# How do I loop and render through a list of predefined widgets?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, mobile, widget

So I have a list of predefined choices that I defined below

```
final List<DropdownMenuItem> grades = <DropdownMenuItem>[
    DropdownMenuItem(value: "Highschool", child: Text('Highschool')),
    DropdownMenuItem(value: "Senior High", child: Text('Senior High')),
    DropdownMenuItem(value: "College", child: Text('College'))];
```

And what I want to do is traverse through the list and put it under the drop down menu

```
 Form(
          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: ButtonTheme(
            alignedDropdown: true,
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              value: defState,
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  defState = newValue!;
                });
              },
              items: grades.map((items) => return items),
              hint: Text("Grade"),
            ),
          )),
        )
```

But it's giving me these two errors

```
The argument type 'Iterable<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>?'.

Unexpected text 'return'.
Try removing the text.
```

Is there a way to iterate the list so I can just immediately return?

Comment: Or just ````items: grades````

Comment: tried both still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

First, arrow functions don't need the `return` keyword. For example, the following 2 functions are equivalent:

```dart
grades.map((_) => 'hello')

grades.map((_) {
  return 'hello';
})
```

Secondly, the error message says: "you gave me an `Iterable<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>`, but I need a `List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>`".

You're creating a `DropdownButton<String>`, which takes a `List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>` as its `items` parameter, but you pass in `grades.map( ... )`.

`map()` is defined in `Iterable`, and has the following signature:

```dart
Iterable<T> map<T>(T f(E e))
```

This is a little bit opaque, but crucially, it returns an `Iterable<T>`, where `T` is the return type of the function you pass in, for example:

```dart
List<int> ints = [1, 2, 3];
Iterable<String> strings = ints.map((i) => i.toString());
```

To fix your problem, you should do the following:

1. instead of having a final field with widgets inside, make it a function. You should avoid caching widgets like this (unless they are `const`) as it interferes with hot-reload. Importantly, the function should also specify the type of `DropdownMenuItem` it returns:

```dart
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> get grades => [
  DropdownMenuItem<String>(...),
  ...
]
```

2. Your map function is invalid, but if you remove the return keyword, it would be `(items) => items`, which is the identity function (i.e. it does nothing). You can remove this and it will work.
   Alternatively, if you want to call some function, you then need to call `toList()` on the result, since `items` expects a list:

```dart
  items: grades,
   
  // or

  items: grades.map((grade) => ...).toList(),
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of `grades` list to `List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>`:

```
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> grades = [
    DropdownMenuItem(value: "Highschool", child: Text('Highschool')),
    DropdownMenuItem(value: "Senior High", child: Text('Senior High')),
    DropdownMenuItem(value: "College", child: Text('College'))
  ];
```

And just use `grades` instead of a map:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
  value: defState,
  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
    setState(() {
      defState = newValue!;
    });
  },
  items: grades,
  hint: Text("Grade"),
),
```